# Apache Camel Restlet Consumer and Producer

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, https, apache-camel, restlet

I want to use a camel component that provides ability to consume and produce RESTful resources.

For this instance, I want to use camel **restlet** component.
Everything works fine with restlet component, i have successfully implemented restlet consumer using REST DSL. However I few questions:

**Questions**

1) Is it safe to enable restlet as async ? I have [read](http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html) restlet async could cause some problems. is that still correct ? how i can increase service performance? should i use jetty instead? how?

2) how i can use restlet as producer such that i can make HTTPS calls to multiple HTTP services? any examples?

3) What other camel component can be used as consumer and producer as Restful services, is Jetty/CXF easy to configure?

4) How I can enable LDAP security with components (servlet/restlet/jetty...) that provide HTTP based endpoints for consuming and producing HTTP request.

thank you. I am using latest version of camel 2.18.2 with spring-boot 4.

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1)
Yes its still a bug/issue in restlet itself

Ad 2)
Check the unit tests of camel-restlet for producer examples

Ad 3)
Check the components listed on rest-dsl documentation and then CXF-RS can also do rest

Ad 4)
That is component specific if they offer any security. Check the documentation.

And your questions are too many and too broad to give better help. Try out some more yourself first.

Comment: thank you @Claus lbsen. If async is still a bug in restlet, what options do you suggest for concurrent service access? 
I guess CXF-RS might not be a viable solution, as it doesn't support REST DSL.
In nutshell, I am looking for camel component that supports/handles concurrent access, HTTPS (server + client) and LDAP security.

Comment: They all allow concurrent access. Async is just a way of avoiding non-blocking threads waiting for a response. Doing this is more complex than a synchronous request-reply scenario.